# React-native nested linear gradient shift on both platform

Tags: react-native, nested, linear-gradients

[image]

Component with nested gradient

```
<View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
  <Text style={{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontSize: 24,

  }}>
    First
    <LinearGradientText
      textComponent={Text}
    showGradient
    >
      <Text>second</Text>
    </LinearGradientText>
    third
  </Text>
</View>
```

Component with Linear Gradient

```
export const LinearGradientText: React.FC\<Props\> = props =\> {

const TextComponent = props.textComponent ?? Text;

return (
\<View\>
\<MaskedView
maskElement={
\<TextComponent {...props} style={\[props.style, {fontSize: 24}\]} /\>
}
\\>
\<LinearGradient
colors={\[
props?.firstColor ?? 'pink',
props?.secondColor ?? 'blue',
\]}
start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
style={\[props.style\]}
\\>
\<TextComponent
{...props}
style={\[props.style, { opacity: 0, fontSize: 24 }\]}
/\>
\</LinearGradient\>
\</MaskedView\>
\</View\>
);
};
```

I can't resolve the problem with gradient text shifting, but I need to use gradient text in nested text, for an example "Good enough, [[username]]".

It works perfectly only for plain text, any tips how can I achieve this?